# How can I build a new project to Github using bash?

Tags: ubuntu, git

I am trying to learn git. How can I put the file `juna.py` to Github in a new project? I am working in Ubuntu. I tried

```
git init

Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/jaakko/juna/.git/

(base) jaakko@jaakko-Lenovo-IdeaPad-L340-17IWL:~/juna$ git add juna.py

(base) jaakko@jaakko-Lenovo-IdeaPad-L340-17IWL:~/juna$ git commit

On branch master

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: You should first add the file using `git add filename` commit the file with `git commit -m "init"` and then `git remote add origin <githubrepourlhere> `. At last we push the commit with `git push origin master`

Comment: Also check out the following link: https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line

Comment: The output `Reinitialized existing Git repository ...` suggests that this directory is already a git repo. The commit command may not work here because `juna.py` has already been commited to the repo and there are no new changes. As the other commenters have said, you then need to `git push` to your remote Github repo.

Answer (score 0):

you might after adding & committing your files in local branch :

```
$git remote add origin remote

$ git remote -v
```

now you can push datas in it from git push command